# How to rearrange two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to rearrange column x1 in the order '2016,2017,2018' and I want column x2 to be in ascending order. Column x3 should not be in ascending order.

my data

```
g <- data.frame("x1" = c(2018,2017,2018,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2018),
                "x2" = c(2,2,5,1,4,3,2,1,1),
                "x3" = c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29))
```

I am using a large dataset but this is a sample of my data.

I tried the formula below but I was only able to rearrange column `x1` in the order '2016,2017,2018'. However, I was not able to make column x2 in ascending order.

```
# **step 1**

cycle_order <- function(x) {
    order(ave(x, x, FUN=seq_along), x)
}

#**step 2 **

X <- g[cycle_order(g$x1), ]
```

I would like my expected result to be:

> X1: 2016,2017,2018,2016,2017,2018,2016,2017,2018

> X2: 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5

> X3: 24,28,29,27,22,21,26,25,23

Comment: I have pasted my expected output

Answer (score 1):

We may use `arrange` in a specific order of the columns

```
library(dplyr)
g %>%
  arrange(x2, x1, x3)
```

-output

```
    x1 x2 x3
1 2016  1 24
2 2017  1 28
3 2018  1 29
4 2016  2 27
5 2017  2 22
6 2018  2 21
7 2016  3 26
8 2017  4 25
9 2018  5 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Arranging year *x1* `by_group` *x2* in ascending order.

```
g %>% 
  group_by(x2) %>% 
  arrange(x1, .by_group = T) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 9 × 3
     x1    x2    x3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2016     1    24
2  2017     1    28
3  2018     1    29
4  2016     2    27
5  2017     2    22
6  2018     2    21
7  2016     3    26
8  2017     4    25
9  2018     5    23
```